# Simplifying IF-Statements on a RadioButtonList

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

Hi i am wondering if there is any way of simplifying the following IF-Statement. I have 47 questions to go through and i really dont want to have this repeating throughout. Im not familiar with c# and would like a hand.

```
protected void GA_Total(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Generalized Anxiety Total 
    int GATotal = 0;
    Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(GATotal);

    //-----------Question 1----------------

    if (RadioButtonList.Items[0].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 0;
    }
    if (RadioButtonList.Items[1].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 1;
    }
    if (RadioButtonList.Items[2].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 2;
    }
    if (RadioButtonList.Items[3].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 3;
    }

    //-----------Question 13----------------

    if (RadioButtonList1.Items[0].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 0;
    }
    if (RadioButtonList1.Items[1].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 1;
    }
    if (RadioButtonList1.Items[2].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 2;
    }
    if (RadioButtonList1.Items[3].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 3;
    }

    //-----------Question 22----------------

    if (RadioButtonList2.Items[0].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 0;
    }
    if (RadioButtonList2.Items[1].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 1;
    }
    if (RadioButtonList2.Items[2].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 2;
    }
    if (RadioButtonList2.Items[3].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 3;
    }

    //-----------Question 27----------------

    if (RadioButtonList3.Items[0].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 0;
    }
    if (RadioButtonList3.Items[1].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 1;
    }
    if (RadioButtonList3.Items[2].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 2;
    }
    if (RadioButtonList3.Items[3].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 3;
    }

    //-----------Question 35----------------

    if (RadioButtonList4.Items[0].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 0;
    }
    if (RadioButtonList4.Items[1].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 1;
    }
    if (RadioButtonList4.Items[2].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 2;
    }
    if (RadioButtonList4.Items[3].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 3;
    }

    //-----------Question 37----------------

    if (RadioButtonList5.Items[0].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 0;
    }
    if (RadioButtonList5.Items[1].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 1;
    }
    if (RadioButtonList5.Items[2].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 2;
    }
    if (RadioButtonList5.Items[3].Selected)
    {
        GATotal = GATotal + 3;
    }

    //------------Results-------------------

    Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(GATotal);
}
```

Comment: Hint: the number you're using to increment `GATotal` is the same as the number you're using to index the `RadioButtonList`s. You can get the index of the selected button using `RadioButtonList.SelectedIndex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically adding the index of the item to GATOTAL, why not use the SelectedIndex of the RadioButtonList directly

e.g.

```
GATotal += RadioButtonList.SelectedIndex + 
           RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex + 
           RadioButtonList2.SelectedIndex +  
           RadioButtonList3.SelectedIndex + 
           RadioButtonList4.SelectedIndex + 
           RadioButtonList5.SelectedIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GATotal += RadioButtonList.SelectedIndex + RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach will make it easy if you want to assign different values to selected items:

```
protected void GA_Total(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Generalized Anxiety Total 
    int GATotal = 0;

    GATotal += sumSelectedItems(radioButtonList);
    GATotal += sumSelectedItems(radioButtonList1);
    GATotal += sumSelectedItems(radioButtonList2);
    GATotal += sumSelectedItems(radioButtonList3);
    GATotal += sumSelectedItems(radioButtonList4);
    GATotal += sumSelectedItems(radioButtonList5);

    Label1.Text = GATotal.toString();
}


private int sumSelectedItems(RadioButtonList list)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (list.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            sum += i;
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have all the radio buttons in Table

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server"><asp:RadioButtonList runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList></asp:Table>
```

**Below code works for any number of radiobuttons.**

```
foreach (Control ctrl in Table1.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is RadioButtonList)
    {  
    RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList)ctrl;

    for (int i = 0; i < rbl.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (rbl.Items[i].Selected)
        {
           GATotal+= RadioButtonList.SelectedIndex;

        }
    }
}
```

}